# Uglify: generate source map but don't append sourceMappingURL comment

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, source-maps, uglifyjs2

I am using UglifyJS2 to minify javascript source code.

I would like to generate source maps and point to those source maps using the `X-SourceMap` HTTP header, instead of the `//# sourceMappingURL` comment.

So, is there a facility to generate a sourcemap in uglify without appending the sourceMappingURL comment, short of just pulling it out myself?

Comment: How'd you end up solving this for yourself?

Comment: This is possible with the uglify cli because there is a separate `source-map-url` flag. This isn't the case for the node api. You can either pull it out yourself, or monkey patch your uglify. I submitted a patch to uglify2 to address this here but it has not been merged yet: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/pull/639